# create custom gradients in illustrator using patterns

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, patterns

I am new to Illustrator and currently fiddling with some of the more advanced options. I would like to know if it is possible to create custom gradients using patterns in the swatches window that blend into each other. Perhaps by specifying them in the gradient slider. The custom gradient options ive seen on this site seem limited to using the polar grid or custom script.

Comment: It is not possible to blend a color the a pattern the way you want it to be. but you can do it in a different way by defining a new pattern that have some pattern and colors blended together the way you want.

Comment: thanks. is there any post on the site that outlines how to do that?

Comment: draw your pattern in a layer and make your desire gradients as another layer and blend the twp layer with any color blend mood you like and save your pattern as a new swatch pattern like mentioned in this [Link](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/patterns.html)

Comment: used the blend tool for the first time today. will have to learn a lot more but it may do what i want especially with Specified Steps

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

Patterns are *patterns* and can not be used within gradients. Gradients will only allow standard colors within their color stops.